# VBA using a Class as a property of another Class

Tags: class, vba, excel

I am having trouble using a Class that I created as a property in another Class. I have two classes, one called Vertex and the other called Edge. Two of the properties of Edge, Parent and Child, are Vertex objects. Here is a method where I try to use them.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub OrgChart()

Dim Vertices As Collection
Dim Edges As Collection
Dim vParent As Vertex
Dim vChild As Vertex
Dim eEdge As Edge
Dim rEdgeRow As Range

Set rEdgeRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C1")

Do While Len(rEdgeRow(1, 1).Value) > 0

Set vChild = New Vertex
Set vParent = New Vertex
Set eEdge = New Edge

vChild.Name = rEdgeRow(1, 1).Value
vChild.Dummy = False

vParent.Name = rEdgeRow(2, 1).Value
vParent.Dummy = False

eEdge.Parent = vParent
eEdge.Child = vChild
eEdge.Percent = rEdgeRow(3, 1).Value

Set rEdgeRow = rEdgeRow.Offset(1, 0)

Loop

End Sub
```

When I run this, I get the error,

"Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set"

The debugger indicates that it is breaking at the line

```
eEdge.Parent = vParent
```

I assume that the issue has to do with the eEdge.Parent not being initialized, but I tried using

```
Set eEdge.Parent = New Vertex
```

and I got the same issue.

If it will help, I can post the class code as well, though they are fairly simple, only containing Property Get and Property Let functions.

I apologize if I did anything wrong when posting this; this is my first time posting anything on SO.

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: The compiler is suggesting that eEdge is null.

Comment: I suspected that might be the case, but I cannot figure out how to correctly initialize it. Do I need to include some sort of initialization in the Property Let function for the Edge class beyond what I would include for a simple property such as an Int?

Comment: When setting a property which is an object type, you do need to use Set.  You should post the code for the `Parent` property of your `Edge` class.

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond sooner. This seems to be one of my issues. The others had to do with Set as well. I was using Property Let instead of Property Set and I also was not using Set inside of those Property functions. Sorry about such a silly mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might not be understanding this right, but did you try:

```
Set eEdge.Parent = vParent
Set eEdge.Child = vChild
```

If they're objects, you need to use a "Set"

... Also, if this doesn't fix it, can you post the code for your Vertex class - You may need to dim the Parent and Child objects differently in its constructor...

Comment: You can see my comment in response to the other answer. Essentially, yes this is the problem.